# Autodesk Forge - how to get properties of multiple selected objects synchronously

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

In my Extension I have an ID from `this.viewer.getSelection()` array, eg 1234.

I've tried to get properties from this:

`this.viewer.getProperties(1234,function(data) {console.log(data);},function(e1,e2) {console.log("ERROR:",e1,e2);})`

But I see the error:

`Properties failed to load since model does not exist`

Updated question:
How to get properties of **multiple** selected objects **synchronously**?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the [viewer.getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method calls [viewer.model.getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback), and as the error message states, `viewer.model` is not available when the method is called. Note that there could be several different reasons for such scenario:

- the `viewer.getProperties` is called on a different instance of viewer (which does not have any model loaded)
- the `viewer.getProperties` is called before the model has been loaded
- the `viewer.getProperties` is called after the model has been unloaded